# php PDO fetchAll(), simple result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetchall

So many questions about PDO::fetchAll() but still I can't find my answer. I need to fetch my results as it is returned by the MySQL. for example if I have columns `id`, `name`, `age` to be returned like this:

```
array(
   "id"=array(1,2,3),
   "name"=array("xy","by","cy"),
   "age" = array(32,34,35)
)
```

I know I can make a function and iterate through the list and put them in the array manually, but I want to know if there is a direct way using fetchAll('magic').

Comment: No there is not. With `fetchAll()` you just get all rows as subArray

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php see `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN`, that's as close as you're gonna get.

Comment: You could rearrange the fetchAll result list via `array_column` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
<?php
function returnResultAsArray()
{
    $test=NULL;
    //  ..... connection and query here
    $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($results as $row) 
    {
        $test['id'][]=$row['id'];
        $test['name'][]=$row['name'];
        $test['age'][]=$row['age'];
    }
    return $test;
}
?>
```

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: I have a function similar to this one, but I was thinking of a straight forward way, something like `var_dump($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP));` I don't know which combinations I should use to get what I want.